# Plotly equivalent to fig.axis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.dates.WeekdayLocator(interval=X))

Tags: python, plotly

I've been trying to find some sort of equivalent function in plotly for: `fig.axis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.dates.WeekdayLocator(interval=2))`

Anyone have any idea?

I already have a barplot and simply want to change the xticks for my dates. Instead of being auto, I'd like them to be ex. every week.

It would seem the closest I got to was to create the range manually, I was hoping to avoid that if possible.

Currently I have this in plotly:

[image]

which is done like the following:

```
    bar_plot = px.bar(df1, x="Date", y="Number of Tests", color='State', barmode='group', color_discrete_map={'Pass':'green','Fail':'red'})
```

and I would like the Axis to look something like this (from matplotlib):
[image]

Comment: https://plotly.com/python/tick-formatting/ this should be able to help

Comment: Yea I've looked through it before but nothing stands out unfortunately.

Comment: Could you add a picture/more detailed explanation of what you’re trying to achieve? Maybe add what your getting using plotly (what your trying to fix) and what you got in matplotlib (what you are trying to get)

Comment: Sure. Sorry, I thought it was clear from the description

Comment: what does your data look like, is it sorted by weeks or simply by months? Maybe attach your code (including your data) so that it is easier to find a solution

Comment: Data is sorted by dates, DD/MM/YYYY

Comment: Just updated again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to sort by weeks, you can update the x-axis and update the `dtick` like this:

```
fig.update_xaxes(type="date", dtick= 86400000.0 * 7)
```

In your case you can just replace `fig` with `bar_plot`, and the `86400000.0` represents a day, so you can have the ticks be within a span of any number days you would like.

If you want do do months, you can simply replace the `dtick= 86400000.0 * 7` with `dtick= "M1"`(you can change the one to change the number of months in the interval

You can also add a `'tick0'` which would allow you to set your first tick if you wanted to change that.